# Current user context in SharePoint modern page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, user

I am using modern SharePoint Pages. I would like to display the current user name with some text like "Hey (current user), welcome to our site".

What are the ways I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you want this for particular site page or all the modern pages in site?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I need this for a particular site page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this for a particular site page, you can use the [Modern Script editor web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor).

After adding web part on your page, enable `_spPageContextInfo` option in Modern Script Editor Web Part:

[image]

Then you can add below code to get the current user name:

```
<p id="pWelcomeMsg"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("pWelcomeMsg").innerHTML = "Hey " + _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName + ", welcome to our site";

</script>
```

**Output**:

[image]

Check this article for installing this web part on your site: [Add The Script Editor Webpart back to SharePoint Modern Experience](https://medium.com/niftit-sharepoint-blog/add-the-script-editor-webpart-back-to-sharepoint-modern-experience-688a7b7208e4)

Comment: Hi Sumanth, did you try this? Is it working for you?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, when you mean you can use the Modern Script editor webpart, Do I have need to have knowledge on SPFx to use those files? I am new to Github too! Can you please direct me..

Comment: If you don't have SPFx knowledge, download the SPFx package from [here](http://spjsfiles.com/?dir=SharePoint%20JavaScripts%2FModernCEWP) - check [this](https://spjsblog.com/modern-cewp/). Add `.sppkg` file to [app catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog) - also check [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page). Then you can add web part to your site page & the code as mentioned above.

Comment: Ganesh, Here are the steps I did - Downloaded v1.0.0.1 file > created an appcatalog site i.e., /sites/appcataglog > added the .sppkg file to Distributed apps for SharePoint. When I checked the properties of the .sppkg file everything seems good i.e., Deployed is Yes, App Package Error Messages shows "No Errors". But next when I go to my test site and find for "Apps from your organization", I didnt find this newly added app. Help me!

Comment: Hi Ganesh, Any help on this?

Comment: Did you check-in the .sppkg file? Also, you can try by making it available for all subsites in site collection.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I have tried above steps but not able to find in Site Contents. Unfortunately, I can see this as a webpart available when I edited the modern page. Finally it is done. Thank you so much. But a final question - Is this .sppkg file trustable? Will there be any breaches?

Comment: I have not developed this web part so I am not 100% sure about it. But it is publicly available & I have used it before without any problem.

Comment: Ganesh, will this context work when external users are accessing the page? I found there are issues when external users are accessing the page.

Comment: What is the issue? I just tried with one external user on my SharePoint site & it is showing the user name correctly.

Comment: Unable to load .js file error.  [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
Failed to load component "ba9171e8-1e09-4ce9-87aa-XXXXXX" (ModernCewpWebPart). Original error: Failed to load path dependency "jQuery" from component "ba9171e8-1e09-4ce9-87aa-XXXXXX" (ModernCewpWebPart). Original error: Error loading https://component-id.invalid/ba9171e8-1e09-4ce9-XXXXXXX_0.0.1/jQuery
 Unable to load script https://tenant/sites/appcatalog/ClientSideAssets/1887252b-c1c6-4054-XXXXXXXXXX/moderncewp-jquery_default_220afd743d9e9643852e31a135a9f3ae.js

Comment: Maybe this is related to permissions of external users on app catalog site. Check if they have at least Read permissions on app catalog.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. Yes, its a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the same result is by building and deploying an spfx solution to the app catalog.
As @Ganesh mentioned the modern script editor, it's ok as a solution, but i always find myself needing of some other feature that could provide usefull.
A complete guide of how to build and deploy an spfx solution with custom user greeting can be found [here.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/navigation-bar-in-spfx-with-current-user-greetings2)

You can neglect the part where the navigation bar is created and cut out that part of the code.

In order to setup the various build tools you can follow [this documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment).